# Windows BAT - IF statement fails in FOR loop

Tags: windows, if-statement, for-loop, batch-file

So I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but nothing came to me. I have narrowed it down to a small case, so please let me know your thoughts.

I have a directory of files (1-a.txt and 1-b.txt) and a batch file like this:

```
for %%X in (1) do ^
fc %%X-a.txt %%X-b.txt > tmp.txt &^
if errorlevel 0 (echo 5) else (echo 6) &^
echo 7
```

Basically, I want it to echo 5 if the files are the same and 6, 7 if they are different.
However, it ALWAYS echos 5. Echo 7 is ignored entirely.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Rule of thumb - if you find yourself needing more than one simple loop ... or any kind of control structures or data manipulation ... then Run!  Don't Walk ... to the nearest scripting language.  Powershell, Perl, VBscript  ... ANYTHING but a .bat file.  IMHO...

Comment: I know, but I am just trying to increase my knowledge and become a better programmer ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if errorlevel` is true when the error level is *at least* 0. It's always a *greater than or equal* comparison:

```
C:\>help if
Performs conditional processing in batch programs.

...

  ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                    returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                    specified.
```

Usually you can just switch the branches around:

```
if errorlevel 1 (echo 6) else (echo 5)
```

In your case I'd also advise you to use parentheses to group statements:

```
for %%X in (1) do (
  fc %%X-a.txt %%X-b.txt > tmp.txt
  if errorlevel 1 (echo 6) else (echo 5)
  echo 7
)
```

As another option to the explicit `if` after the program call there are also operators that run another command depending on the outcome of the previous one:

```
fc %%X-a.txt %%X-b.txt > tmp.txt && echo 5 || echo 6
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Any idea why my "echo 7" was never being run in the previous .bat script?

Comment: Your if statement was of the form "if a then b else c & d".  This is interpreted as "if a then (b) else (c & d)".  The d statement will only be executed if a is false, which was never the case.  The echo 7 would have run if you'd put the if statement in brackets: "(if errorlevel 0 (echo 5) else (echo 6)) & echo 7"